# Laravel 5.4 - Eloquent Relationship Update

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a question on updating a table in Laravel. I have a `User` and `Car` Model. Example as below,

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Car::class);
    }
}
```

**Car.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Car extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }    
}
```

For the update, I am using below codes on my controller,

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
      // validations here

      $car = Car::find($id);

      $carDetail = Car::where('id', $id)
      ->update([
          'vehicle_no'=> $request->vehicle_no,
          'location_id' => $request->location_id,
          'created_at' => $request->created_at,
      ]);

      $user = $car->user()
      ->update([
          'name'=> $request->name,
          'ic_number'=> $request->ic_number,
      ]);

      return back();
}
```

I am able to update the table but want to know if I am doing it right.

Is there an accurate or a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you use relation between two models it's better if you update them as they are in the relation. so yes you'r almost right . but for more information it's better if you use separate REQUEST file other than in the controller. one more thing based on experience it's better when you update the relation first . overall it will be something like this :

```
 public function update(SomeRequestFile $request, $id)
 {

     $car = Car::find($id);

     $user = $car->user()
         ->update([
             'name'=> $request->name,
             'ic_number'=> $request->ic_number,
         ]);
     $carDetail = Car::where('id', $id)
         ->update([
             'vehicle_no'=> $request->vehicle_no,
             'location_id' => $request->location_id,
             'created_at' => $request->created_at,
         ]);
     return back();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the separate request file, do you mean to separate them on different method?

Comment: @Khairul no , i mean like this : php artisan make:request SomethingRequest... then you can modify validations in there , for more info :https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#creating-form-requests .. hope this help